# Is it correct to say "Please hold on to the subhandrail and railings while walking up the stairs"?

Tags: word-usage, word-request, phrase-usage, phrase-request

[image]

Look at the picture, I am not sure if I understand the stairs' anatomy correctly.

Do we say "**main handrail**", "**subhandrail**", "**a railing**" as shown in the above picture?

A flight of stairs might have 1 main handrail and some subhandrails. It might also have many railings.

My child is too short to hold the main handrail. In this case,

Is it correct to say "**Please hold on to the subhandrail and railings while walking up the stairs**"?

Comment: Is there even such a thing as a _sub-handrail_? The lower rails are to stop people from falling through the space under the handrail - traditional wooden 'banisters' have upright supports.

Comment: I don't think I've ever seen the word *subhandrail* before and I can hardly find the word being used anywhere.  And *railing* just refers to the entire thing in your picture.

Comment: @stangdon, look at the dictionry "https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/railing?q=railing" 

a railing is "**a fence made of metal bars that go straight upwards; one of these bars**", so one of these bars can also be called a railing, right

Comment: @Tom It sounds very strange to this US English speaker to call a single upright bar "a railing".  You might call them collectively "railings", or the entire thing "a railing", but I wouldn't point to one of them and say "This is **a railing**.  There are **many railings** here."

Answer (score 1):

For a small child, you might just say "Hold onto the rail.", while showing them the appropriate place to grasp. It's a safety warning, so don't confuse the child with fine distinctions.